# JavaScript regex for email fails. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is a ready-baked regex that I got from the internet just to see how regex works in JavaScript (and jQuery). Here is my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var regexp = new RegExp(([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}));
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var result = regexp.test( $("#email").val() );
            if(result){
                $("form").submit();
            }else{
                alert("Invalid Email Address");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, the form always submits despite entering a wrong email address.

I have read on how `test()` works. It know that it returns the right answer and then advances a pointer to the next value. So if it returns true, the pointer points to false. I do not see how that can be a problem here.

**what is wrong here?** :)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <center>
        <form name="subscription" method="post" action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">
            <input type="text" name="email" size="30" id="email"></input>
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: create jsfiddle also.

Comment: @PratikJoshi With all due respect, I feel you are being a little disrespectful here.

Comment: Please check console errors first-> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: @LittleChild , With all respect , Why do you feel so ?I mean if you expect good answer ,then you should not assume ,that we know your html, So please post jsfiddle ,and include HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double **escape** your Regex. Try this-

```
var regexp = new RegExp("([\\w-\\.]+)@((?:[\\w]+\\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})");
```

**Edit**

It is always helpful to log the result so that you see if your regexp string is correct, eg:

```
console.log("([\\w-\\.]+)@((?:[\\w]+\\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})");
console.log("([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})");
```

Comment: Done !! Working !! :-)

Comment: Few more minutes to go :)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex initialization should be string and it should be escaped.

```
var regexp = new RegExp("([\\w\\.-]+)@((?:[\\w]+\\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})");
```

You can also use:

```
var regexp = /([\w\.-]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})/;
```

Comment: ah ! I didnt see the tutorial mention that :)

Comment: uhm... still doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by not solving the problem?

Comment: still it shows console error

Comment: @AmitJoki : `Range out of order in character class `

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead?

```
<input type="email" />
```

Comment: Yes, that is an option but the idea is to see how regex work. That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

write it a regex (note the `/`)

Regex: `var regexp = new RegExp(/([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})/);`

Answer (score 0):

In Html5, There is a new attribute type="email" is available.

Instead of using input type="text"

Please try this!

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;